# StreamBuilder Snapshot ConnectionState.done not working

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I use Cloud Firestore for data. In this case basic chat app. What I want is control the scroll of Listview.Builder. I couldnt control scroll because it is not working before content build of course. So What I tried is waiting snapshot connection done

`snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done`

But program can not run **ConnectionState.done**

```
 bool _isMe;
  ScrollController _ListViewController = ScrollController();
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: messages.snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("hata", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black));
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) { /////////not working
              print(33);
              print(_ListViewController.hasClients);
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
             print(44);
              return Text(
                "bekleniyor",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              );
            }
            return Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _ListViewController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['user_id'] ==
                        sharedPrefs.UyeId.toString()) {
                      _isMe = true;
                    } else {
                      _isMe = false;
                    }

                    return Container(...)
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Program runs perfectly. It fetch data realtime and send data realtime. I just need the info that new snapshot come.

Answer (score 0):

Granting that you've all the required `Firebase` permissions, you could try to use `ConnectionState.active`:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: messages.snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) print('error');
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active)  print('active');
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) print('waiting');
    return Container();
  },
);
```

Comment: I am really not sure that works for me. Because whenever I opened keyboard StreamBuilder reflesh itself and run .active and .waiting commands. I don't think it should work like this but I cant be sure. I try to figure out when the new data come